# Best way to use an array that is returned from a function immediately in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that returns an array and I want to check that a certain value is not set in the array.

```
function testFunction() {
    return array('key' => 404)
}

if (testFunction()['key'] < 404) {
    // stay calm and carry on
}
else {
    // uh oh
}
```

I understand that the above will not work in php 5.3 (or anything below), however, I'd like to know what I should do in the above case. That is - what should I call the temporary array I create for the if statement? Or is there another way of dealing with this situation?

The following is what I would roughly do currently:

```
function testFunction() {
    return array('key' => 404)
}

$test_array = testFunction();

if ($test_array['key'] < 404) {
    // stay calm and carry on
}
else {
    // uh oh
}
```

Is this an acceptable thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, .. you want to simply check whether a certain key in an array is set to a certain value.

You can't do this directly on the function call because [older PHP versions don't support array dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282051/590790). You are right when saying you'll need an intermediate variable.

The only question remaining is what to name it. Considering that the variable will probably be situated in a really small scope, don't worry about it too much. There is a saying which says, **the bigger the scope, the bigger the name**. You could just name it `$list`.

Old replies:

> Your code does something else as what
>   you describe? If you want to see
>   whether a given value is present in
>   the array, use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).
>
> UPDATE:
>
> I believe I understand what you are
>   trying to accomplish now. You just
>   want to see whether the key is set?
>
> [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
>
> PHP has got a pretty good online API,
>   be sure to check it for existing
>   implementations when looking for a
>   solution.

Comment: According to the code, Jonathan also wants to compare against the value mapped to that key if there is one.

Comment: I want to know if a specific key has the value 404. so in_array() will not work because the value may exist somewhere else and array_key_exist will not work because I know the key exists. I want to know if a specific key I know is there has the value 404.

Comment: @Jonathan Mayhak: K, I finally understand your question now. ;p I updated the answer.

Comment: I was just curious if there was some standard in php for dealing with this situation. Good to know what I've been doing is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not match your code. You ask to check that a key does not exist in the array, yet you are actually testing *the value mapped to that key* against some other value, presumably doing something else if the key doesn't exist.

```
$result = testFunction();
if (!isset($result['key']) || $result['key'] < 404) {
    // ok
}
else {
    // panic
}
```

You can create a helper method with a suggestive name that does the full check and use that in your `if` clause.

```
function omgWeGotTheDreaded404() {
    $result = testFunction();
    return isset($result['key'] && $result['key'] >= 404;
}

...

if (omgWeGotTheDreaded404()) ...
```

Comment: Your answer is the same thing I wrote above for the second example. I know I can do what you wrote. I want to know if what we both wrote is the best way. What do you think is a good thing to name the temporary array? (you used $result and I used $test_array)

Comment: Steven's answer about the name is good advice. It lives such a short life, give it a terse name. My point is that I'd still put it inside a function that returns `bool` so you don't need a temporary array outside the function. If you only do this in one place, it's not of much value.